# MySql cluster with proxy configuration load data query issue

Tags: mysql, load, cluster-computing, haproxy

I have mysql cluster with 3 nodes. I am using a proxy to connect to this mysql server.
The load balancing and all are handled by the proxy(eg: HAProxy).

My issue is that i am not able to do load data query from my application server.
It's throwing file not found exception but the file is present in the application server.(It may be checking the proxy server location for the operation).

I suspect due to mysql cluster & proxy configuration it's causing this unusual error.

Is it possible to run load data to above mentioned like MySql cluster setup?

Comment: You need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` so it reads the file from the client, not the server.

Comment: For my curiosity, how you split read/write queries using haproxy?

Comment: @Slava i am not expert on mysql cluster setup. According to my understanding proxy has the ability to identify the current mysql master node. Using this it can manage read/write operation

Comment: @Barmar i am using the same load data local in file only. Without proxy if i connect mysql master node directly it will work. Mysql network router also will be a option. I want to know whether load data(local in file) is is available with proxy